# Can Rust macros parse JSON?

Tags: json, rust

I'd like to define constant values by using a JSON configuration file, something like this:

```
enum E {
    ONE = get!(include_json!("a.json"), 0),
    TWO = get!(include_json!("a.json"), 1),
}
```

Is there any way to parse JSON at compile-time?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that I mistook the enum definition, so modified the definition.

Comment: Good! Then I think the `build.rs` approach is feasible. Isolate this definition in the smallest file possible and you're good to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to parse json at compile-time. In order of "involvement":

- using the [`build.rs` script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) to generate your source code during build; it's technically cheating, of course, but it's easy,
- using a `const` function in combination with the [`include_str!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html), it would require nightly and I am not sure whether the compile-time engine is powerful enough at the time being,
- writing a compiler plugin, which is what `include_str!` is, it also requires nightly and the interface may change with each release of the compiler.

Thus I would advise you to use the `build.rs` script approach for now since it's both simple and stable.